# Using SVD to get 3D rotation matrix of N-Dimensional points

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am trying to rewrite an algorithm which uses Singular Value Decomposition for finding the rigid rotation matrix which maximizes the overlap between two sets of points.

My target is a bit different, in that my points are 3+N dimensional, but I want to find the optimal rotation matrix in just the first three dimensions.

A rotation matrix for 3+3D would for example look like this:

$$R_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
 R11&  R12&  R13&  &  & \\ 
 R21&  R22&  R23 &  &  & \\ 
 R31&  R32 & R33 &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &1  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  &1  & \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

In the standard 3D case, the optimal rotation can be easily found using Singular Value Decomposition. However, my target for "optimality" is not in the first three dimensions, but in the ones after that. So my quantity to minimize roughly said is:

$$ \min_{R_3} \sum  w_i r^2(y_i, R_3x) $$

Where $w_i$ is a weight term that I want to use to factor in the distances in higher dimensions.

I have found a modified version of the [Kabsch Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm#Computation_of_the_optimal_rotation_matrix), which takes in weights per point (see: [Least-Squares Rigid Motion Using SVD](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/svd_rot.pdf)).

This algorithm finds the weighted Cross-Covariance Matrix $H$ as follows:

$$H = X \cdot diag(W) \cdot Y^T$$

(Whereas the Kabsch Algorithm simply uses $H = X Y^T $)

Since I want regions that are similar in the higher-dimensional space to overlap, I want to weigh that sum with the inverse of the high-dimensional distances, lets call them $d_f(y_i,x_j)$.

Since there is a weight for every part of the sum (so $N^2$ weights), I cannot get away with using a diagonal matrix of weights, but need a full matrix of weights:

$$ W_{ij} = \frac{1}{d_f(y_i,x_j)}$$

Is there any reason why the weighted Kabsch Algorithm should not work with a full weight matrix W rather than a diagonal matrix, and is there a more suitable function for weighing with $d_f(y_i,xj)$ for this problem than $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: Could you please provide a bit of background for the original SVD algorithm you're referring to?

Comment: @Zim I edited the question, apparently it is known as the Kabsch Algorithm.

Comment: If you want just the first 3 coordinates, why don't you just ignore the rest and use Kabsch?

Comment: Because I'm not interested in matching the shape of the point set, but the dimensions beyond that. Imagine having randomly sampled fields, and wanting to match those fields by where their gradients look similar, not (primarily) by where the spatial structure of the point set looks similar. Or maybe more intuitively, imagine having two photographs of the same scene featuring a dog, at slightly different angles and translations, and wanting to match them by where the dog is. The point set for both is a regular grid, but simply overlaying the grids doesn't help.

Comment: @tobu if I understand your problem, rotating the first 3 coordinates cannot change the other $N$ corrdinates, so you cannot improve their score. Can you rephrase exactly what the target function you are trying to optimize is?

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I have edited the question with my idea of how to tackle the problem. I have found a weighted Kabsch Algorithm, which might just do the trick - but I'm not entirely sure if it would work that way.